# Hover Popups with Additional links on Image

Tags: php, javascript, html, popup, hover

I am trying to build a page where i am having an image. Now I want to do a task that when ever mouse is taken over a certain part of image , that image with some links popup as a Mouse Hover Functionality.

Like For E.g. I have a map of US(as an Image on my Webpage) , and in that when I take the mouse over its State ( say: Texas) then the image of Texas ( which is embedded as Hyper link ) pops up in larger view and that image have additional links of Cities and user should be able to click those links and can reach the page of that City.

I Hope my Query is Clear.

Comment: It sounds very much like what you want is an HTML image map. Just do a quick search on "image map". There are many examples of how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use image maps to break into areas(for eg states). You can some jquery library like **maphighlight**, to show the hovering effect. And finally since you want to show dynamic content in the pop up boxes, you can create a generic template which gets populated based off the id being passed and then you can make **ajax request** to that page and pass the id along. Also **colorbox**(is a type of lightbox) supports image maps, so you can populate it using ajax, just by passing the urul in href tags of each area.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I'll look out for that. And will be back with more issues. :) :)